# force create_task execution

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I used `asyncio.create_task()` only to realize that the task is fed to the task engine at a very late time. To make late time of execution obvious, I put some IO requests in the code below:

```
import asyncio
import requests

async def func2():
    # always executes last
    print("async asf")

def func1():
    asyncio.create_task(func2())

async def main():
    print("main started")
    func1()
    print("main ended")

    # lets do some IO requests to give python plenty of time to execute func2
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get("https://youtube.com")

    # this should be the last thing printed, but it is not
    print(response.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This prints:

```
main started
main ended
200
async asf
```

Although I expected `async asf` to be before `200`

How do you artificially trigger task execution? Is there some semantic sugar?

Comment: All the rest of your code is synchronous, you never yield control to the running loop after you create the task

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. Can you modify it with an example?

Comment: Try adding `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to your `main` function to allow the task to run

Comment: @sudden_appearance true, would just need to refactor a few functions and calls so he's not mixing sync and async

Comment: Thanks.  If `func2` takes a very long time to execute, than the code execution will be noticeably blocked at the time `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is called. The next line after `await asyncio.sleep(0)` will be executed only after `func2` is done. Thats no good. I just want `func2` to be fired and forget about it without any blocking of the main thread (or python equivalent)

Comment: Asyncio event loops are, for all intents and purposes, "single-threaded". Only one task will run at a time, so unless the running task yields control back to the event loop, by using `await` for example, then nothing else will run unless it's being run in a thread or other process

Comment: Thank you for the third time :D I was hoping the behaviour would be similar to javascript async/await, but I guess similarity ends with the terminology. Is there anything similar to c# `Task.Run()` in python?

Comment: You can run in a different thread with `asyncio.to_thread` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads

Comment: Okay. I went ahead and replaced `asyncio.create_task(func2())` with `asyncio.to_thread(func2())`. Python complains that `coroutine 'to_thread' was never awaited`. If I await it, than this is not fire and forget, but rather fire and carefully monitor when is the correct time for execution...

Comment: `async/await` in Python and Javascript are the same, you have to actually use `await` appropriately to allow other code to run. Your question states one situation and then your comments highlight that you're actually dealing with other issues, so you should update your question to be more specific.